# WPF application doesn't draw correctly when another application is running in fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

My application is a bit more complicated than the following, but I've distilled the problem to a simple case.

I have a textbox bound to an object's property. The binding works fine when working from inside the app.

My application runs a TCP server in another thread that receives messages from a mod I've created for a game (the game is Binding of Isaac, if that's any help). The mod sends messages to my application when the user presses a key in-game. When the server receives a message, it invokes a change in the bound property through the app's dispatcher, like so:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
    TestModel.Number = sum;
});
```

This works fine when the game is windowed; the textbox is updated according to the message and drawn correctly. When the game is in fullscreen, however, and I alt-tab back to my application after sending the message, the textbox text doesn't update until I mouse-over. I'm pretty certain that the text value of the textbox is updated correctly, but it just isn't redrawn while the game is fullscreen, and mousing over triggers a redraw.

Strangely, within the first 10 or so seconds of starting my application, the textbox updates correctly even when the game is fullscreened. After that, the issue starts up.

I would greatly appreciate any insight or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely a driver problem. Try disabling hardware acceleration on startup:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Performance will suffer, but it should render properly.

Comment: Yep, just a minute before you posted this I found [the same issue](https://github.com/neowutran/ShinraMeter/issues/279) on another project. This does fix it. I appreciate you answering anyway, though.